# C style up cast to same hierachical level

Tags: c++, casting

I have the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class IA 
{
    public:
    virtual void printA() = 0;
    virtual ~IA(){};
};

class IB 
{
    public:
    virtual void printB() = 0;
    virtual ~IB(){}
};

class IC : public IA, public IB 
{
    public:
    void printA() {cout << "hello world a" << endl; }
    void printB() {cout << "hello world b" << endl; }
};

void func(IB* p)
{
    p->printB();
}

int main()
{
    IA* p = new IC;
    p->printA();
    cout << "cast to ib" << endl;
    func((IB*)p);
    return 0;
}
```

after I executed the code, I got the following result:

```
hello world a  
cast to ib 
hello world a
```

my question is, what compiler does with `(IB*)p` that cause `func` calls to `p->printB()` but get result `hello a` instead of `hello b`??

what is behind the scene of cast?? what compiler generates for casting??
if I change to `func(dynamic_cast<IB*>(p))`, it got `print b` is the correct result.

Answer (score 5):

`(IB*)p` here does `reinterpret_cast<IB*>(p)`, however, that yields an invalid pointer because `IA` and `IB` are not related.

`dynamic_cast<IB*>(p)` does the right thing because it inspects the typeinfo for the object `*p` and finds that the object derives both `IA` and `IB` and returns a suitably adjusted pointer to `IB` sub-object of `IC`. Note that `IA` pointer coincides with a pointer to object `IC`, unlike `IB`:

```
struct IA {
    virtual ~IA(){};
};

struct IB {
    virtual ~IB(){}
};

struct IC : IA, IB {};

int main() {
    IA* p = new IC;
    std::cout << "IA: " << p << '\n';
    std::cout << "IB: " << dynamic_cast<IB*>(p) << '\n';
    std::cout << "IC: " << dynamic_cast<IC*>(p) << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
IA: 0x21c1c20
IB: 0x21c1c28
IC: 0x21c1c20
```

---

Full info of how C-style cast works in C++: [explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast):

> When the C-style cast expression is encountered, the compiler attempts to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this order:
>
> 1. `const_cast<new_type>(expression);`
> 2. `static_cast<new_type>(expression)`, with extensions: pointer or reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even if the base class is inaccessible (that is, this cast ignores the private inheritance specifier). Same applies to casting pointer to member to pointer to member of unambiguous non-virtual base;
> 3. `static_cast` (with extensions) followed by `const_cast`;
> 4. `reinterpret_cast<new_type>(expression);`
> 5. `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`.
>      The first choice that satisfies the requirements of the respective cast operator is selected, even if it cannot be compiled. If the cast can be interpreted in more than one way as static_cast followed by a const_cast, it cannot be compiled.
>      In addition, C-style cast notation is allowed to cast from, to, and between pointers to incomplete class type. If both `expression` and `new_type` are pointers to incomplete class types, it's unspecified whether `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` gets selected.

Note that C-style case never does `dynamic_cast`.

C-style casts are considered poor practice in C++ because their meaning silently changes when types and hierarchies change. Use C++ casts for robust code.